# scipy sparse matrix: Index out of range

Tags: python, scipy, nlp, sparse-matrix

I want to run textrank against a large corpus (just my dev env is using 17K sentences)

Hence I have used scipy `dok_matrix`. However, when assigning the first value to my sparse matrix (i.e., `similarity_matrix[1][0]`), I get the following error, despite seeing in pycharm debug that my dok_matrix is of size 17K by 17k.

`IndexError: row index (1) out of range`

What have I done wrong?

```
 def _score_generator(self, sentences, sentence_vectors):
    sentence_count = len(sentences)
    similarity_matrix = dok_matrix((sentence_count, sentence_count), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(len(sentences)):
        for j in range(len(sentences)):
            if i != j:
                similarity_matrix[i][j] = cosine_similarity(sentence_vectors[i].reshape(1, 100), sentence_vectors[j].reshape(1, 100))[0, 0]


    nx_graph = nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(similarity_matrix)
    scores = nx.pagerank(nx_graph)
    return scores
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple:
`similarity_matrix[i,j]`
I'll leave it here in case anyone else ends up making the same cognitive slip as I did